# Unable to access routes after deployed Laravel Project on WHM server

Tags: php, laravel-8, cpanel, whm

I can only access welcome route of laravel  after deploye my project on WHM server. If I am try to get "/login" or "/user" somekind of this site shows me Not found 404 Error. Please help me.

I want run access other routes except "/" index route but getting 404 error.

Comment: show your laravel.log see if it gives an error. Show the nginx.conf of your server, see I it does something weird with anything after '/'

Comment: logs are empaty

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.